# Flex Child Height not Stretching to Full Height of Parent (using align-self stretch)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.appShopSummaryContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryProductWrap {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryImg {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 26.667%;
  background: green;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
}
.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryInfo {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100%; /* not working */
  /* doesn't work: align-self: stretch; */
}
.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryMoreInfoBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #214291;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="appShopSummaryContainer">
  <!-- FOR EACH THING DO THIS -->
  <div class="appShopSummaryProductWrap">
    <a href="#" class="appShopSummaryImg" style="background:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/982021/pexels-photo-982021.jpeg')"></a>
    <div class="appShopSummaryInfo">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <a href="#" class="appShopSummaryMoreInfoBtn">More Information</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ENDFOREACH -->
</div>
```

I've had a look at some other stackoverflow answers to similar questions, but none work in this situation. Not sure why, but cannot get the orange div to expand to the full height of it's parent.

Setting a height to 100% obviously won't work since the parent doesn't have a fixed height, but aligning itself as stretch also fails to stretch the height.

If anyone can solve this, can someone explain why the align stretch won't work, and why their solution does? Thanks for any help here.

Comment: looks like it works with displaying it as a grid, but still curious to know why flex doesn't work (grid solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOygmR)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?
you have to add `align-items: stretch;` to the parent not the item itself
check out this [css flex guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

add `align-items: stretch;` to `.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryProductWrap` and remove `height: 100%;` from `.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryInfo` and add `justify-content: center;` to `.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryInfo`

```css
.appShopSummaryContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryProductWrap {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryImg {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 26.667%;
  background: green;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
}
.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryInfo {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}
.appShopSummaryContainer .appShopSummaryMoreInfoBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #214291;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="appShopSummaryContainer">
  <!-- FOR EACH THING DO THIS -->
  <div class="appShopSummaryProductWrap">
    <a href="#" class="appShopSummaryImg" style="background:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/982021/pexels-photo-982021.jpeg')"></a>
    <div class="appShopSummaryInfo">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <a href="#" class="appShopSummaryMoreInfoBtn">More Information</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ENDFOREACH -->
</div>
```